# Missing required Parameter:post for new controller action

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have a controller called `publish` added to existing `posts_controller.rb`
when I access `http://localhost:3000/posts/15/publish` it returs `Missing required Parameter:post` in the browser.

I'm not sure what I am missing. 
Could someone point the missing piece of the puzzle? thank you in advance

posts_controller.rb

```
  # PUBLISH /post/1/publish
  def publish
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @post.publish = true
     @post.published_at = Time.now.utc
     respond_to do |format|
       if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
         format.html 
       else
         format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Something went wrong. Try again.' }
       #  format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end   
  end
```

publish.html.erb

```
  <h1>PUBLISHED POST</h1>
```

routes.rb

```
  match 'posts/:id/publish' => 'posts#publish' , :as => :publish
  match 'posts/:id/unpublish' => 'posts#unpublish', :as => :unpublish
  resources :posts
```

I'm using strong_parameters & this is the permitted parameters explicitly defined in posts_controller.rb

```
 def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:id, :rental_type, :rent_amt, :street_address, :city, :state, :description, :pet_friendly, :duration, :occupancy, :zip, {:roommate_preference => []}, :latitude, :longitude, :start_date, :publish, :published_at, :user_id)
    end
```

log:

```
Started GET "/posts/15/publish" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-19 02:07:29 -0700
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Post.page.
Processing by PostsController#publish as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  Post Load (15.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "15"]]
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 400 Bad Request in 603ms (Views: 62.5ms | ActiveRecord: 382.7ms)
```

Comment: anyone? Please let me know if i've not provided enough info

Comment: I've figured it out 
changed @post.update_attributes(post_params) to  @post.update_attributes(params[:post])

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out changed `@post.update_attributes(post_params)` to `@post.update_attributes(params[:post])`